# Zoom inside a center of a picture instead of changing height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a gallery in the center of my website - it has a dynamic width (bootstrap column), and fixed height (`80vh`). I want the images inside to have `50%` width of the container, and `350px` height:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6" style="height: 80vh;">
    <div style="overflow-y: auto;">
      <div style="width: 50%; height: 350px; float: left">
        <img src="..." style="min-width: 100%; height: 350px;">
      </div>
      <div style="width: 50%; height: 350px; float: left">
        <img src="..." style="min-width: 100%; height: 350px;">
      </div>
      <div style="width: 50%; height: 350px; float: left">
        <img src="..." style="min-width: 100%; height: 350px;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>
```

The thing is that when I resize the website, the width is changed, and the height stays the same - the image gets resized. Is there a better solution? I've been thinking about zooming on an image instead of resizing the whole thing - is this possible?

Comment: Give height also in percentage!

Comment: can you put it in js fiddle?

Comment: replace `height: 350px` with `max-height: 350px`

Answer (score 0):

If you strictly have to use a `350px` height for each gallery item and want images to maintain aspect ratio, you can use `background-size: cover` to zoom in and crop the images instead of resizing them. See: https://jsfiddle.net/nelonoel/c8zsscuL/